# How to add `Simple Framework` to gradle dependencies

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, simple-framework

I'm trying to use Simple Framework in my project. Here is the dependency in XML format.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I've tried converting the dependency to Gradle acceptable format.

```
compile 'simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
```

But, I don't think it's correct. What is the correct gradle dependecy?

Comment: Double check your dependency on Gradle, the dependency that you posted here is for Hibernate

Comment: (face palm!) is this correct? 'simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'

Comment: `'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'`. See the Gradle tab here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.simpleframework/simple-xml/2.7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct Gradle dependency is:

`compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'`

For Android, you also have to exclude dependencies as they are already in the Android SDK

```
compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```